# Losing data, Map containing String and Integer

Tags: java

I have a program that takes data from a text file. The file is formatted such as

```
Date/Time Tip From (Name)
Message(If one was left)
(Tipped Amount)    (Total Tips Recieved)
```

I have been able to get my code to separate it out and put it in a Map such that it adds up all the tips per name and outputs it in descending fashion.

E.g

```
INPUT ----------------------------------
Dec. 14, 2013, 2:31 a.m.     Tip from rs
25  24986
Dec. 14, 2013, 2:27 a.m.     Tip from ro
100 24961
Dec. 14, 2013, 2:27 a.m.     Tip from rs
15  24861
Dec. 14, 2013, 2:25 a.m.     Tip from da
3   24846
OUTPUT-----------------------------------
ro=100
rs=40
da=3
```

I have now run into an issue. I have found I am losing data and cant figure out why. In the text file there are over 1,000 entrys so around 2,000 lines of text. One of the tippers, X, when calculated by hand, tipped 1990. When run, the program only calculates 1690, 300 less than what was actually tipped. I am at a loss on trying to debug this to find out where the data could be getting deleted or skipped over.

Here is an excerpt from my code relevant to the calculators being performed

```
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.contains("Tip from")) { // Finds the line that contains
                                                    // the tippers name
                final String tipperName = line.substring(line
                        .indexOf("from ") + 5);
                currentTipper = tipperName;

            } else if (line.substring(0, 1).matches("\\d")) { // finds the
                                                                // line that
                                                                // contains
                                                                // the
                                                                // tipped
                                                                // amount
                final Integer tipValue = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0,
                        line.indexOf("\t")));
                // here we store the tip in the map. If we have a record
                // we
                // sum, else
                // we store as is
                tipsByName
                        .put(currentTipper,
                                (tipsByName.get(currentTipper) == null ? 0
                                        : tipsByName.get(currentTipper))
                                        + tipValue);

            } else { // if line doesnt contain a name or a tip, skips to
                        // next line
                bufferedReader.readLine();

            }
        }
```

If the full code would be more helpful, please let me know and I will edit the post.

Thanks!

Comment: Dont think thats the problem.. But always trim() the line.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have duplicated entries, that's why you 'lose data'. Before you insert an entry to your map try to see if the key is already there.

Comment: and also keep in mind that a map searches for equal entries, not for identical (so `String a="tip7"` and `String b="tip7"` will override each other, although those may be two different objects)

Comment: Suggesting a Map<String, List<Integer>> to map tipper to multiple tips.

Comment: @Stroboskop yep, that's a way to go.

Comment: So say X tipped 25, X tipped 50, Y tipped 25, Z tipped 10 Should it output to X=75 Y=25 Z=10 or sometime completely different? If it is different how do I overcome this?

How would I go about integrating the <String,List<Integer>> into my code. Sorry Im new to Java and have taken on a bigger task than I can chew. Maps are very new to me

Comment: When you declare `tipsByName` as `Map<String, List<Integer>> ` then each time you'll want to insert a new entry into it you'll need to check if the key of the entry is already in the `Map`. If yes, you just append the entry to the list associated with the key. If not, you will need to create a new `List`, put the entry into it, and put the new `List` into the `Map`.

Comment: So I will need to create another list just to handle the tipped amount and then i would add that to the Map?

Answer (score 0):

On a side note instead of writing the code for parsing the text file, since you have a fixed delimiter separating the fields try using `OsterMillerUtils CSVParser` to ease your coding hassles http://ostermiller.org/utils/javadoc/CSVParser.html.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to parse the full file (Java 7):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {

    public static <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> Map<K, V>
    sortByValueDescending( Map<K, V> map )
    {
        List<Map.Entry<K, V>> list =
                new LinkedList<Map.Entry<K, V>>( map.entrySet() );
        Collections.sort( list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>>()
        {
            public int compare( Map.Entry<K, V> o1, Map.Entry<K, V> o2 )
            {
                return (o2.getValue()).compareTo( o1.getValue() );
            }
        } );

        Map<K, V> result = new LinkedHashMap<K, V>();
        for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : list)
        {
            result.put( entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() );
        }
        return result;
    }

    static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding)
            throws IOException
    {
        byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
        return encoding.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(encoded)).toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        //String sourceString = readFile(args[1], Charset.defaultCharset());
        String sourceString = "Dec. 14, 2013, 2:31 a.m.     Tip from rs\n" +
                "25  24986\n" +
                "Dec. 14, 2013, 2:27 a.m.     Tip from ro\n" +
                "100 24961\n" +
                "Dec. 14, 2013, 2:27 a.m.     Tip from rs\n" +
                "15  24861\n" +
                "Dec. 14, 2013, 2:25 a.m.     Tip from da\n" +
                "3   24846";

        Pattern re = Pattern.compile("^[\\w]{3}\\.\\s\\d{1,2},\\s\\d{4},\\s\\d{1,2}:\\d{2}\\s[ap]\\.m\\.\\s+Tip\\sfrom\\s(\\w+)\\s*^(\\d+)\\s+\\d+\\s*"
                ,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE);

        Map<String,Integer> tips = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        Matcher m = re.matcher(sourceString);
        while (m.find()){
            String server = m.group(1);
            Integer tip = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));

            Integer serverTips = tips.get(server);
            if(serverTips == null) serverTips = 0;
            serverTips +=  tip;

            tips.put(server, serverTips);
        }

        Map<String,Integer> sortedTips = sortByValueDescending(tips);
        for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : sortedTips.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey()+"="+ entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ro=100
rs=40
da=3
```

You can replace `args[1]` with the path to your file and change the encoding if you do not use the default encoding.

Comment: I tried this. I am still getting issues with losing data :( I would post the entire txt document but I think StackOverflow might kill me haha something near 2,500 lines of text